# Importing whatsapp text file within a new dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to import and analyse a whatsapp chat (only one file/conversation). I am following this article to do it:

My data looks like as follows:

```
[28/07/2018, 01:39:21] User1: \u200eMessages to this chat and calls are now secured with end-to-end encryption.\n\u200e[28/07/2018, 01:39:21] Martin: \u200e<attached: 00000002-PHOTO-2018-07-28-01-39-20.jpg>\n\u200e[28/07/2018, 01:40:38] Martin: \u200e<attached: 00000003-PHOTO-2018-07-28-01-40-37.jpg>\n\u200e[28/07/2018, 02:06:08] Martin: \u200e<attached: 00000004-PHOTO-2018-07-28-02-06-06.jpg>\n\u200e[28/07/2018, 02:06:08] Martin: \u200e<attached: 00000005-PHOTO-2018-07-28-02-06-07.jpg>\n[28/07/2018, 16:53:01] User1: Noi stiamo andando a Londra, ti serve qualcosa.? Divertiti, saluti \n[29/07/2018, 16:13:35] User1: \u200eMissed video call\n[02/08/2018, 17:12:07] User1: \u200eMissed voice call\n[02/08/2018, 17:35:02]
```

and so on.
What I can see is that:

- each message starts with `\n`
- *date* and *time* are included in `[ ]`
- after a black space, after `[]`, there is the *username*, followed by `:` ;
- then there is the *message* (`Missed video call`, `Missed voice call` or just text).

What I would like to do is build a dataframe having:

- one column for the date;
- one column for the user;
- one column for the message (preferably by removing Missed voice/video call from the analysis)

After importing the file

```
file = open(r'path/file.txt',mode='r',encoding="utf8")
data = file.read()
file.close()
```

I have tried to clean it by

```
pattern = re.compile('\d+:\d+\s+-\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?):\s+')
messengers = re.findall(pattern,data)
```

However when I try to build the dataframe, the dataframe is empty because off the wrong patterns.

Could you please give me any advice on how to build a non-empty dataframe with those columns?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
pattern = re.compile('(\[.*\])\s*(\w+)\:\s*(.*)')
re.findall(pattern,data)
```

This gives something like this:

```
[('[28/07/2018, 01:39:21]', 'User1', '\u200eMessages to this chat and calls are now secured with end-to-end encryption.'), ('[28/07/2018, 01:39:21]', 'Martin', '\u200e<attached: 00000002-PHOTO-2018-07-28-01-39-20.jpg>'), ('[28/07/2018, 01:40:38]', 'Martin', '\u200e<attached: 00000003-PHOTO-2018-07-28-01-40-37.jpg>'), ('[28/07/2018, 02:06:08]', 'Martin', '\u200e<attached: 00000004-PHOTO-2018-07-28-02-06-06.jpg>'), ('[28/07/2018, 02:06:08]', 'Martin', '\u200e<attached: 00000005-PHOTO-2018-07-28-02-06-07.jpg>'), ('[28/07/2018, 16:53:01]', 'User1', 'Noi stiamo andando a Londra, ti serve qualcosa.? Divertiti, saluti '), ('[29/07/2018, 16:13:35]', 'User1', '\u200eMissed video call'), ('[02/08/2018, 17:12:07]', 'User1', '\u200eMissed voice call')]
```

You can clean this as per your needs. But it captures the date-time, username and the rest of the message as separate groups.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you have a specific issue in your pattern, I'm not seeing the date format accounted for anywhere in there.

For simplicity, since each message is a line, start with splitting by line.
Then apply your regex there, or even more simply, you could `partition` on `]`, that'd give you the date on one side and then the user + message on the other. Then partition the user+message side on `:` and now you'd have that split to user and message.
For parsing the date you could use [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or `strptime` in the standard library.